# Jquery toggle add z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

I'm trying to do what Toogle open up div test as the sample image:

[image]

Css:

```
.area1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index:99;
}
.area2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Jquery

```
$("#Go2").click(function () {
    $(".area1").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
    $(".area2").hide();

});
$("#Go").click(function () {
    $(".area2").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
    $(".area1").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gislef/kcve9qhg/

I trying usage z-index, but do not work

---

**SOLUTION**

http://jsfiddle.net/gislef/kcve9qhg/6/

Thank you @D.Gramm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want z-index to work you need to have the position set at absolute or relative. Then z-index will take effect.

Comment: Now you just need to change the position of the buttons and colors

Comment: Instead of toggling width I would hide the red box off to the right and setting #test's overflow to hidden. Then on click it could slide in from the right side.

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite understand this last explanation, but the div test needs to be fixed. Div needs to stand still

Comment: Finally got it: D, detail solution in my question. Thank you so much